# How can I commit only solved files during merging in git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

In git I made a cherry-pick and I have to merge files now, but there is lots of them, so I want to commit only files, which conflicts are already solved without "full merge". How can I do that? Of course without commiting unsolved files.

Answer (score 0):

You can `git reset .` to reset all files, and then `git add` only the ones you've already resolved their conflicts.